# How to set default pose of model from Blender? (Exported as FBX)

Tags: unity, animation, blender

I have a model that has lots of animation clips(actions).

[image]

Before export as FBX, I set the pose to named "default" pose and exported as FBX like this.

[image]

But in Unity, it's changed to first animation clip in animation list in Blender!

[image]

I try to fix it, but there is nothing I can do. I can't change the order of animations in Blender and Unity either.

This wasn't first time, I had same issues before but I just ignored because it's fine in game play, but I really want to fix it this time.

What I want is set "default" pose in edit mode in Unity(not play mode). How do I set "default" pose as default, not first animation clip in the list?

Using Blender 2.78, and Unity 2017.3.0f3.

Comment: then simply set the animation to it? Check the animation components

Comment: @Sidar Simply set the animation to what?

Comment: @Sidar And what is animation components? Do you meaning Animation Controller, or animation import settings? I already did both. Your answer is too vague.

Comment: Unity doesn't care about animation order. The clips are generated based on your import file. You then set the animation clip in mechanim or whatever the animation components do now. I haven't touched unity in a while.

Comment: @Sidar That doesn't make any sense, because when "Default" clip was first clip, there wasn't any problem. After I added new actions starts with "B"(named Blocked), it located before "Default" clip and now Unity set the pose by default to "Blocked", not "Default". If Unity doesn't care about animation order, why it suddenly changed? Also in Animator, default state is "Draw" but still in "Blocked" state in edit mode.

Comment: @Sidar As I mentioned in the text, it's not first time to me. Unity always did like this. Is there anything I should check something else?

Comment: It might pick the first one it encounters sure, I'm just saying that it doesn't really have any significance other than that. There are a few topics on this some even suggest a script, but if naming shifts the order why not add a _ to your default -> `_default` this puts it first

Comment: @Sidar Okay, I just change to _default now it's turning back to default pose. I don't like this method but seems this is the only one I can solve this. I'd better rename it in Unity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sidar said, change name of "Default" clip to "_Default" should be work. It's not complete solution, might be fix for now.

Answer (score 2):

You should Know that Unity takes the "default pose" from the first frame of the first animation.

Also Unity classifies them as they are in blender:

[image]

[Solution]
1 - Always create an Idle Animation and set the "default pose" in the first frame, and rename it to be the first animation.

or

2 - set "default pose" on the first frame of your first animation(action) in blender, so Unity can understand that's the default pose.

(don't forgit to Reimport the .FBX in Unity after making changes)